# Как преобразовать переменную типа str в кортеже в int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

У меня есть функция `max_population` которая должна выводить `('eu_kyiv', 24834)`. Но выводит `('eu_kyiv', '24834')`

Как мне сделать что бы `('24834')` выводилось как `int`

Вот мой код:

```
import re

def max_population(data):
    a = []
    for i in data:
        b = re.findall(r',\S+_\S+,[0-9]+', i)
        a += [[ b for b in i.split(',') if b] for i in b]
return max(a, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))


data = ["id,name,poppulation,is_capital",
        "3024,eu_kyiv,24834,y",
        "3025,eu_volynia,20231,n",
        "3026,eu_galych,23745,n",
        "4892,me_medina,18038,n",
        "4401,af_cairo,18946,y",
        "4700,me_tabriz,13421,n",
        "4899,me_bagdad,22723,y",
        "6600,af_zulu,09720,n"]

print(max_population(data))
```

Comment: А что должно получиться, если eu_kyiv перевести в число? Структура везде одинаковая и четкая. [1] списка не переводи в число, а [2] переводи.

Comment: Тут конечно можно без регулярных выражений обойтись. Просто split(',')

Answer (score 0):

Не очень эффективное решение. Возможно, кто то предложит лучше.

```py
def max_population(data):
    data.pop(0) # Get rid of unused info
    populations = []
    for city_info in data:
        info = city_info.split(",")
        populations.append(int(info[2]))
    row = data[populations.index(max(populations))]
    spl = row.split(",")
    return spl[1], int(spl[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Преобразовывайте в int только то, что число:

```
    a += [[ int(b) if b.isdigit() else b for b in i.split(',') if b] for i in b]
```

Или вот вам другой вариант функции:

```
def max_population(data):
    res = max(data[1:], key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[2])).split(',')
    return [res[1], int(res[2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно воспользоваться библиотекой `Pandas`, она сама сообразит, что это числа:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = ["id,name,poppulation,is_capital",
        "3024,eu_kyiv,24834,y",
        "3025,eu_volynia,20231,n",
        "3026,eu_galych,23745,n",
        "4892,me_medina,18038,n",
        "4401,af_cairo,18946,y",
        "4700,me_tabriz,13421,n",
        "4899,me_bagdad,22723,y",
        "6600,af_zulu,09720,n"]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(data)))
print(tuple(df.sort_values('poppulation', ascending=False).loc[0, ['name','poppulation']]))
```

Вывод:

```
('eu_kyiv', 24834)
```

- читаем список и преобразовываем в `pandas.DataFrame`
- сортируем датафрейм по убыванию по полю `poppulation`
- берём первую строку в отсортированном и указанные поля в ней
- преобразуем в кортеж